# Precompile JSP in JBoss 7

Tags: java, jsp, jboss7.x

We are migrating our application from JBoss 5 to Jboss 7. We want to precompile the JSP's to see all of them are getting compiled fine rather than accessing each one of them and check.

From whatever I have read, I have not been able to find a concrete solution to this problem.

Does anybody have any suggestions on how this can be achieved?

Answer (score 0):

You can precompile the jsp page by passing jsp_precompile=true in the parameter. For example if you want to precompile the xyj.jsp running on localhost, you have to do http://x.x.x.x:8080/xyz.jsp?jsp_precompile=true this will only precompile the jsp and will not execute it.

Instead of doing it manually, you can write up a small ant script which will find out all your jsp pages inside web application and fire GET method call for each of jsp with jsp_precompile=true in it. This will automate the whole process of achieving it.
This is the only way to precompile the jsp with out executing it.

Comment: This means it will have to compiled and running before you can do this, which defeats the purpose of pre-compile.